# JS does not work on Android

Tags: javascript, android

This js code segment doesn't work on Android. 
Maybe could this be because android does not support some of the classes?

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.broker_management_table th .btn_sort_on a', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.btn_sort_on').find('a').attr('data-status', 'false');
        $('.btn_sort_on').find('strong').removeClass('active');

        var $self = $(this);
        $self.closest('strong').addClass('active');
        $self.attr('data-status', 'true');

        sendFilters();
});
```

Comment: Are you running it as part of regular webpage via browser (i.e. Chrome) or as a part of hybrid application (i.e. inside WebView, via Phonegap/Cordova)?

Comment: Its work on WebKit. But not on the HTC android

Comment: Did you try to use .on('tap')  ?